# Ruby on Rails how to put javascript inside head tag?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

i'm using ruby 2/rails 4 and trying to put my javascript in `<head>` but all javascripts is going to end of the page,

i'm trying to use this code but don't works:

in app/views/layouts/index.html.haml:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{ content: 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'http-equiv' => 'Content-Type' }
    %meta{ content: 'text', name: 'description'}
    :javascript
      //code...
```

or puting this code in the end of app/views/index.html.haml:

```
- content_for :head do
  :javascript
    //code...
```

this two alternatives don't works to me, someone can bring me a light?

Comment: Why are you adding code to your layout file instead of using `javascript_include_tag` and/or your application.js?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do it:

1. I think you have to define "yield :head" in the head and then you can use the content_for :head do block in your pages.

   !!!
   %html
     %head
       %meta{ content: 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'http-equiv' => 'Content-Type' }
       %meta{ content: 'text', name: 'description'}

   ```
   yield :head
   ```

In the page app/views/home/index.html.haml you can use content_for method:

```
- content_for :head do
  :javascript
     console.log('test');
```

2.

```
%script{ type: 'text/javascript }
  console.log('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :plain

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    :plain
      <script ../>
```